# Requesting Runtime permissions on Xiaomi devices

Tags: android-permissions

When requesting permissions on devices with API level 23+ the documentation states you need to request each **permission** you need, and in case you are requesting a permission from a **permissions group** that you already have access to the permission is granted by by the system.
[Handle the permissions request response](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request)

However, while adjusting my app to target API level 23 I noted that it is sufficient to request permission for one representative of the group - and the following checks for other permissions from the same group get **PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED** when checking if has permission.

For example if I requested permission for **READ_CONTACTS** and then checked if I had permission to **WRITE_CONTACTS** the answer was yes.

I tested my code changes on **Nexus** and **One Plus** devices and started releasing the app.

Then I started seeing reports on **Fabric** where the only device failing the permissions handling was **Xiaomi** and the question is how to request permissions on those devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to actually follow the guidelines in the documentation and request all the permissions in a **dangerous permissions group** instead of asking for one representative. (obviously only the permissions listed in your manifest xml)

When issuing a single request with multiple permissions from the same group the user sees only one dialog.

I know that the documentation states [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups) and this looks like a safer approach

> Any permission can belong to a permission group, including normal permissions and permissions defined by your app. However, a permission's group only affects the user experience if the permission is dangerous. You can ignore the permission group for normal permissions.

But so far I implemented a specific request for all permissions only for **Xiaomi** and all other devices are working fine while requesting one permission from a group.

**Update:**
according to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#rmp) the correct behavior is the way that was implemented in Xiaomi - and it's a bug that was fixed in **Oreo**

Comment: can you share some code how did you implemented that